# Create a Pandas/NumPy function to find when of values in a series change?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Within a DataFrame, I have a column called "States" that describes where various events happened, therefore many rows are repeated and then change to another state:

```
States
- California
- California
- California
- California
- California
- New Mexico
- New Mexico
- New Mexico
- Hawaii
- California
```

I'm trying to run a pandas function that will assign a variable to each state but have it be unique for each time the state changes. So that even though states are repeated, they won't get the same value as the last time they're in the list. From my above example, I would get:

```
new_column
- 1
- 1
- 1
- 1
- 1
- 2
- 2
- 2
- 3
- 4 #even though this is 'California', it's a new,unique value
```

I've currently tried

```
def new_id(stateVal):
    x = Kentucky #first state in the list that I'm comparing to
    y = 1 #the unique value
    if stateVal == x:
        return y
    elif stateVal != x:
        x == w
        y++
        return y
    else:
        return 0
```

And haven't gotten it to properly work when I apply it to the STATE column in my dataset. Is there a predefined function in Pandas or NumPy to help with this?

Comment: `y++` is not valid python. But I'm racking my brain to find the canonical for this :/

Comment: is y++ equivalent to y+=1?

Comment: @DerekEden pretty sure it is, but it just shows that the code hasn't actually been tested before being posted, or is coming from memory. In any case, there's a neat way to do this, I'm just having a brain fart in trying to find it

Answer (score 2):

you could do it like this, comparing each element to the next:

```
count=1
for i,row in enumerate(df['state'] == df['state'].shift(-1)):
    if row:
        df.at[i,'new_column'] = count
    else:
        df.at[i,'new_column'] = count
        count+=1

df['new_column'] = df['new_column'].astype(int) #convert to int if necessary
```

there might be a cleaner way to avoid the loop but I think it principle it's what youre looking for

EDIT one-liner, gives same output:

```
df['new_column'] = df['state'].ne(df['state'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Comment: The one-liner should be significantly faster as it's vectorized. Upvote for that, the initial method might as well be removed from the answer.

Comment: Terrific!! Thank you so much, I was able to get those numbers and didn't have to convert to int